# what is the diffrence between layer 5 session and tcp session

Tags: tcp

I found out that layer 5 session and tcp session both handle with processes of end devices.
but what are their diffrences?

1. does one handle process abd the other aplications?
2. can one run over the other?

Comment: TCP does not observe the OSI model. It has a different, prior, model of its own. It is futile to try to map the models together, and the OSI model is defunct. Just use the TCP model. It appals me that they are still teaching OSI 20+ years after its demise.

Answer (score 0):

TCP establishes a *socket connection*. While that *may* be seen as a session in some protocols, it might not in others. For instance, a single web session may use multiple, even concurrent TCP connections, each potentially pipelining multiple HTTP requests. FTP uses a TCP control connection that spawns TCP data connections.

OSI layers 5 and 6 do not exist in the TCP/IP model. In real life, *sessions* are a concept within the application layer. Usually, sessions are held together by some kind of token - for HTTP, both cookies and URL parameters are in use.